# How to use | and & in Java while loop with more than 2 values correctly?

Tags: java

I was practicing with conditions in the while loop and got little bit confused with it.

I have a simple program that should read input from users by console (Using Scanner). If input is not equal to some string value it should output error and ask user to enter it again.

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR NAME : ");
    user=input.next();

    while(!user.equals("admin") && !user.equals("vlad") && !user.equals("user"))
    {
        System.out.println("THIS USERNAME IS NOT REGISTERED");
        user=input.next();
    }
```

So I think when we input admin, the while loop should look something like this :
`while(F && T && T)` and it should break the loop and go to the next instruction, but after input the program crashes.

If we input any value we should get
`while(!F && !F && !F)` and it should execute instruction in the while loop but it doesn't. So what am I doing wrong with these while conditions?

Comment: Perhaps the crash is caused by the code that comes after the loop.

Comment: I have only siwtch(user) after this code ,and the program crashes on the phase of the while loop

Comment: You meant to say in case of `while(!F && !F && !F) ` its not printing `System.out.println("THIS USERNAME IS NOT REGISTRED");` ?

Comment: Issue is with the condition inside while loop

Comment: If by "the program crashes" you mean "the program prints a stacktrace and exits", then you should post the stacktrace, and you should add a comment to your code indicating the line that the stacktrace refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it like below;

You need to have `String user` and use `&&`

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("ENTER YOUR NAME : ");
String user = input.next();

while(!user.equals("admin") && !user.equals("vlad") && !user.equals("user"))
{
    System.out.println("THIS USERNAME IS NOT REGISTRED");
    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR NAME : ");
    user = input.next();
}
```

Comment: Have user declared on the top of the program so i didnt copy that part of the code :) . Alredy tried the OR condition but it just le me to input infinite times the username.

Comment: Are you using JDK6 or 7?  I have put the above code in a main method and was able to run it cleanly. When I enter admin as the username the program stops. otherwise it keeps looping.

Comment: This condition will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Ofcourse it would. Its going to loop until the user enters admin or valid or user as the input value

Comment: I have put this code and now the problem is that i always have the true condition even if I input admin or user

Comment: @VladTimoshin Can you try the code I have updated now. Sorry I had the wrong code pasted.

Comment: @JeromeAnthony yes now it works corectly but i just cant see the diference between your and mine code, so why now it works?

Comment: @VladTimoshin Your original code (if that is what you actually had) had no problems. Any problems were elsewhere, such as running the wrong version of the code.